# issue with ng-change with datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I was trying to use ng-change for a date-picker pop as below but the function is not getting called.Looks like ng-change triggers only when there is a keyboard input which otherwise does not happen with a datepicker-pop.
Has anyone faced this issue or is there a workaround for this?

Code below:

```
<input id="{{modelName}}"
    type="text"
    sort
    datepicker-pop="dd MMMM yyyy"
    class="form-control"
    ng-change="changeInDate()"
    ng-model="formData.expectedDisbursementDate"
    is-open="opened" />
```

Comment: <input id="{{modelName}}" type="text" sort datepicker-pop="dd MMMM yyyy" class="form-control" ng-change="changeInDate()" 
ng-model="formData.expectedDisbursementDate" is-open="opened" />

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you're using that's causing an error?

Comment: I have already posted the code snippet. If that is not the thing which you are asking , could you please elaborate what you exactly require.

Comment: https://github.com/bekos/bootstrap/commit/84e6736fb5f606988187c3caa802747ae0f1a270 check out this link

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting that you are using UI Bootstraps datepicker. In that case you have some miss spellings. The following should work:

```
<input type="text"
 class="form-control"
 datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy"
 ng-model="formData.expectedDisbursementDate"
 ng-change="changeInDate()" 
 is-open="opened" 
 ng-required="true" />
```